# Boost Karma, formatting ints with leading zeros

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

If I have a simple generator:

```
struct MyIntsGen
    : boost::spirit::karma::grammar<boost::spirit::ostream_iterator, std::tuple<int, int, int>()>
{
    MyIntsGen() : MyIntsGen::base_type(start_)
    {

        namespace bsk = boost::spirit::karma;
        start_ = '<' 
            << bsk::int_
            << ','
            << bsk::int_
            << ','
            << bsk::int_
            << '>';
    }

    ~MyIntsGen() = default;
    boost::spirit::karma::rule<boost::spirit::ostream_iterator, std::tuple<int, int, int>()> start_;
};
```

And I run it simply with:

```
std::tuple<int, int, int> ms = { 300, 20, 1 };
std::cout << boost::spirit::karma::format(MyIntsGen(), ms) << std::endl;
```

I see the output you'd expect, `<300,20,1>` but I'd like to pad the numbers with leading zeros. In other words I'd like to see:

`<300,020,001>`

What's an easy way to do this in my rule?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/reference/directive/alignment.html

Comment: @Addy it would be so easy to make that code self-contained. Why don't you? It'll make the barrier to answering 10x lower.